# Нужна помощь в решении проблемы на mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть склад. На складе есть мешки с сахаром определенного веса. В сутки(86400 сек) из каждого мешка можно взять не более 5 кг сахара.

Как высчитать, сколько суммарно сахара, на текущий момент, я могу взять со склада?

В базе 2 таблицы. Первая:

- id мешка
- вес каждого мешка
- время последней транзакции с этим мешком
- вес который мы взяли за последнюю транзакцию

Во вторую я записываю каждую транзакцию:

- id мешка
- время транзакции
- объем транзакции

Первая таблица:

```
id|id_мешка|вес_мешка|last_trans                |вес_последней_транзакции
1   54      80          2016-02-27 12:15:23         3.2
2   84      30          2016-02-25 18:30:53         4
3   126     21          2016-02-27 12:35:07         5
4   127     100          -                          -
```

Вторая:

```
sub_id|id_мешка|trans|time
1       54      1.8     2016-02-27 10:55:54
2       54      3.2     2016-02-27 12:15:23
3       84      4       2016-02-25 18:30:53
4       126     5       2016-02-27 12:35:07
```

Comment: `select id_мешка,  sum(trans) from вторая where time > now() - interval 1 day  group by id_мешка` вот вам сколько взяли. дальше все просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для mysql. Как-то так сейчас не могу проверить

сколько взяли из каждого мешка

```
select id_мешка, sum(trans) 
   from вторая 
 where time > now() - interval 1 day 
 group by id_мешка
```

вот сколько сможем взять со склада

```
select sum(avail) 
  from 
    ( select (5 - ifnull(taken, 0)) avail 
       from первая 
         left join 
            ( select id_мешка, sum(trans) taken
                from вторая 
              where time > now() - interval 1 day 
              group by id_мешка
             ) t
         using (id_мешка) 
     ) a
```

Либо совсем просто, но возможно не соответствует исходной задаче

```
<количество мешков> * 5 - <сумма взятого за сутки>
```

те в субд как-то так

```
select 5 * count(*) - 
       (select sum(trans) from вторая where time > now() - interval 1 day)
   from первая
```